# How can I implement this Fragment based layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a appliaction for tablets. There will be a mainactivity and will include a map on it. And other fragments will be on it.

For example, I think, this [figure](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/62/fragmentr.png) is telling what I want.

[The figure http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/62/fragmentr.png](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/62/fragmentr.png)

Map will always be there and the listview will on it on the left for example. Is it possible on android? And in which way I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can create an XML file which describes the arrangment of the UI elements on the screen and then write the code which initializes and manages these UI elements. Details and examples can be found in the official API guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

In this case you would create a vertical `LinearLayout` with three elements:

- a `TextView` (header),
- a horizontal `LinearLayout` (map and map list) with two elements:

  - a `MapView` for the map
  - a `TextView` for the list
- a horizontal `LinearLayout` (menu) with various `Button` elements

Answer (score 0):

More of a pseudo-approach, but hopefully it'll send you down the right path.

You could use an `ActionBar` as the header, a `MapFragment` and a `ListFragment` for the content itself. The menu is up to you, depending on what you want it to do. :)

Comment: Menu isn't problem. I just want to make this desing. In addition, The map will be on the mainactivity and I will show fragments on activity that has map.